# error when activating anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I have tried activating my conda for a while now, when I do conda env list I get an env like this `"C:\Users\Allaye\Anaconda3"` and I issue this command `'conda activate C:\Users\Allaye\Anaconda3'`,  but when I restart my machine again I still gets the same activate environment error. any help. but write now even the conda command isn't working again..

I don't know what to do now, because it seems when I activate the environment it only on a tempora basics

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're asking but if it's a case of the environment being temporary then that's the whole point because you could have multiple environments

Comment: it means every time I reboot the machine I have to activate the environment again

Comment: Ok, and why would that be an issue?

Comment: If you don't want to have to activate the environment each time, install into the base environment

Comment: I wont have issue with but but sometime even the conda command does not work again, when I issue the conda command it takes me to a python interpreter terminal, where am told to activate my environment, which I wont be able to do because the conda commands are no longer working

Comment: i did that with conda activate C:\Users\Allaye\Anaconda3'  and it show that it is the base env.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow the issue at all. The base environment should be active by default so I don't know what you've done with the setup. I'm probably not going to be able to help you debug this

Comment: if you don't mind let me explain it well to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activating a conda environment applies to the current shell or terminal window only. That way, you can open several terminals and activate different conda environments in each. It's not a persistent setting, you have to repeat it every time you open a terminal to work in a specific conda environment.

You could define aliases or helper scripts for each environment, so you have to do less typing.

Comment: but sometime after a while the conda command does not work again

Comment: and when that happens my anaconda navigator no longer works